# Sometimes import data Mysql in Docker very slow

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a file *.SQL more than 1GB, when I import to Mysql on local or Vagrant, it always successful. But with the same file,  I import to Mysql on Docker, it very very slow (about 10MB / 15 minutes). I have checked many times with the same result.
I tried with many files; it seems to occur with specified files. I don't know the cause. I need help.

This's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2.0"
services:
 database:
  image: "mysql/mysql-server:5.5"
  ports:
   - "3307:3306"
  volumes:
   - "db:/var/lib/mysql"
   - ./sql:/home/sql
  environment:
   MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
 volumes:
  db: {}
```

Comment: It could be that SQL file is transferred from *disk to dockerized mysql* over local TCP/IP connection thus slow and file is not imported via *direct disk read commands*. Copy / Keep SQL file inside container's file system and then try import.

Comment: @SACHIN: It just occur with any files, not all.

Comment: Yes, there is not harm in trying out suggestion. Although it may seem bizarre or may not work. I understand we all learning through sharing our experiences here at wondeful stackoverflow site.

Comment: @SACHIN: Thanks, i tried most of cases but not successful.

Comment: I've raised question's priority

Comment: @SACHIN: thanks you

Answer (score 3):

I use docker in windows ... 
My solution whas moving the .sql file to Docker mysql container and executing the import manually.

- Export .sql from your mysql production server...
- Copy the file into Docker mysql container

`docker cp base_ok.sql docker_mysql_1:/home/base_ok.sql`

- enter into the bash of the docker mysql container

  `docker exec -ti docker_mysql_1 bash`
- import the DDBB

  `mysql -p -u root magento < base_ok.sql`

note that my docker container is docker_mysql_1 you can list all your containers  typing docker ps

Comment: I always move the *.sql file to Docker Container and import. But in this case, it's not effective

Comment: Working for me for initial import. But very slow afterward. I'm using mysql in a container, and expose port 3306 (-p 3306:3306). My application is running on host. With this configuration, access to mysql is 10x slower. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late for answering, but I struggled with this and I think the solution could help others.

I've read a lot, I tried the barrier=0 in my ext4 filesystem but nothing. Finally the simple solution that worked for me was enlarging innodb buffer pool size to a decent value

mysql.cnf:

```
[mysql]
innodb_buffer_pool_size=128M
```

That's it.

You can copy existing conf to a local dir, then mount it:
docker cp -a

```
<container>:/etc/mysql/conf.d mysql_conf
# change mysql.cnf
docker run ... -v /path/to/mysql_conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d ...
```

Or for what I know passing it directly to docker run:

```
docker run ... mysql:latest --innodb-buffer-pool-size=128M
```

#### Update

I discovered that that solution wasn't enough per se, it somehow happen to work sometimes while still so slow on others (not dig in why).

Since I use it just for a development version of mysql on my pc, I'm not particularly worried about data corruption, etc, so I now have:

```
[mysql]
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size=128M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4
innodb_read_io_threads = 4
innodb_write_io_threads = 4

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_file_per_table = 1

innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_doublewrite = 0
innodb_support_xa = 0
innodb_checksums = 0

general_log = 0
slow_query_log = 0

innodb_lru_scan_depth=256
```

Then I launched an optimize table on all tables for just make sure that "innodb_file_per_table" was effective.

Adjust options that scares you most accordingly if you are on a production environment.